# Common code to iterate through different types of collections

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an elegant solution to use common code to iterate through `hash_map`/`unordered_map` and `list`/`vector` collections?

An example:

```
template<typename collection>
class multicast
{
public:
    typedef collection collection_type;

private:
    collection_type& m_channels;

public:
    multicast(collection_type& channels) : m_channels(channels) { }

    void operator ()(const buffer::ptr& head, const buffer::ptr& cnt)
    {
        for each(collection_type::value_type& ch in m_channels)
            ch->send(head, cnt); /* this is where the magic should happen? */
    }
}
```

This code obviously fails to compile when `collection_type` is `unordered_map` since `collection_type::value_type` is a `pair` so the code that access the actual value should be different: `ch.second->send(head, cnt)` instead of `ch->send(head, cnt)`. So what would be the most elegant way to get rid of key part when it is not needed?

Comment: Have you tried partial specialization of your template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
for (auto & x : collection) { do_stuff_with(x); }
```

Alternatively:

```
for (auto it = std::begin(collection), end = std::end(collection); it != end; ++it)
{
    do_stuff_with(*it);
}
```

If neither range-based `for` nor `auto` are available, you could write a template which takes a container `C` and use `C::value_type` and `C::iterator`; or you could make a template which accepts a pair of *iterators* of type `Iter` and uses `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type` for the element value type.

Thirdly, you can use `for_each` and a lambda:

```
std::for_each(colllection.begin(), collection.end(),
              [](collection::value_type & x) { do_stuff_with(x); });
```

To accommodate for both single-element and pair-element containers, you can build a little wrapper:

```
template <typename T> struct get_value_impl
{
    typedef T value_type;
    static value_type & get(T & t) { return t; }
};
template <typename K, typename V> struct get_value_impl<std::pair<K, V>>
{
    typedef V value_type;
    static value_type & get(std::pair<K,V> & p) { return p.second; }
};
template <typename T>
typename get_value_impl<T>::value_type & get_value(T & t)
{
    return get_value_impl<T>::get(t);
}
```

Now you can use `get_value(x)` or `get_value(*it)` to get the value only.

Comment: And he can use `std::for_each` as well, along with lambda (in C++11).

Comment: actually it is 'for each' (range-based loop, vc++11)

Comment: I think the question was about how to deal with the different value_types that some collections provide, not about the actual collection-iterating syntax. Some collections give you the value, and some give the key and the value.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Oh OK, let me add a trait check!

Comment: @MladenJankovic: I added a helper function to extract the value of either type of container.

Comment: Thanks, mate! I was thinking something along those lines, but specialization for std::pair gave me headaches :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that list/vector contains just a value, while map-s contains a pair of key-value. They are not the same thing, and to iterate the same way you shold at least define what part of the pair you are interested in.

Once defined, you essentially need a "derefence" operation that accepts an iterator, and -in case it has as a value_type a pair, return the second element, oterwise just dereference it.

```
// default case, returning itself
template<class T>
T& get_val(T& t) { return t; } 

// case for pair (derefence for a map iterator)
template<class K, class V>
V& get_val(std::pair<const K, V>& s) { return s.second; }

// iterator dereference
template<class Iter>
decltype(get_val(*Iter()) deref_iter(const Iter& i)
{ return get_val(*i); }
```

Of course, `const_iter` version are also required, if needed.

Now:

```
for(auto i=container.begin(); i!=container-end(); ++i)
    do_something_with(deref_iter(i));
```

will be the same whatever the container.